# Dynamic links generated with PHP, open in Popup window

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I am a beginner and have problem. I have a data base from it I am taking date and with functions I am generating links on every product page. When you click on button with link I want to open it in popup window. My problem is that I don't know how to connect JavaScript and this functions because PHP run on server but JavaScript on browser. This is code of URL generator

```
global $currentLanguage;
global $currentTag;

function low($name_certificate) {
    //Lower case everything
    $name_certificate = strtolower($name_certificate);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $name_certificate = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $name_certificate);
    return $name_certificate;
}
$currentLanguage = JFactory::getLanguage();
$currentTag = $currentLanguage->get('tag');
function lang($currentTag) {
    global $lang;
    if     ($currentTag=='en-GB')  {   $lang='en';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='cs-CZ')  {   $lang='cz';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='el-GR')  {   $lang='gr';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='hu-HU')  {   $lang='hu';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='pl-PL')  {   $lang='pl';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='ro-RO')  {   $lang='ro';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='sk-SK')  {   $lang='sk';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='tr-TR')  {   $lang='tr';  }
    elseif ($currentTag=='bg-BG')  {   $lang='bg';  }

return $lang;
}

function urlGenerator($company,$name_certificate){
    global $currentLanguage;
    $ssl='http://example.com';
    $lang=lang($currentLanguage);   
    $company=low($company);
    $name_certificate=low($name_certificate);
    $link=$ssl.'/'.$lang.'/'.$company.'/'.$name_certificate;

return $link;   
}   `
```

All connections are working. 
This is the code of table where I have button and need to be open not in difernet window but popup. This button is a loop acordingwith products:

```
foreach($row as $key => $price){   ?>
        <tr id="price"style="font:15px,arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"> 
        <td style=""><?= $price['year']; if ($price['year']==1 ) {echo 'year'; } else {echo 'years';} ?><br>
    <?= round($price['margin']*$price['buy_price']*$value,$round); echo " ",$currency_sign;?></span></h5></td>
        <td><?php echo 'per_year';?>
    <?= round((($price['margin']*$price['buy_price'])/$price['year'])*$value,$round);echo " ",$currency_sign;?></span></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo buy($idCert,$price['year']); ?> "  target="_blank"><button type="submit"><img src="images/icons/shop_cart.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo 'buy';?></button></a></td></tr>
}
```

Comment: This link could help you if the Joomla module should always display its text  in a popup box: https://www.spiralscripts.co.uk/Joomla-Tips/using-modal-windows-with-joomla.html. Otherwise: what the module echoes _echo "...text..."_ will be displayed within the page at the appropriate location. And, finally, when you wish to create text on the server side that has to be dynamically displayed in a popup box (besides what the joomla module delivers) you should create a separate script for that and you'd need Ajax Javascript code to send requests to the script and accept data to display.

Comment: why don't you just generate the links, like this: `<a href="<?=urlGenerator($company,$name_certificate)?>" target="_blank">...</a>`

Comment: add a unique class such as "popup" to each outputted link from PHP.  Then use jQuery to catch all clicks on those with `$('.popup').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault; // Do popup code here  });`

Comment: @khaitran I have this solution but is not good because it is pointing to other paying system, end user dont have to know it.  (I have this solution now)

Comment: @hherger tx. I am trying to develop it now. I will comment my solution code when I will doen it.